# How to get value from complex object

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to iterate over `p` and select a url

```
p = {
     "photos":[
         {"alt_sizes":[{"url":"img1.png"}]},
         {"alt_sizes":[{"url":"img2.png"}]}
     ]
}
```

What is the most efficient way to get `"url"`?

**Edit**: `"photos"` can have more than two values, and so I need to *iterate*

Comment: writing an efficient code and making it more efficient by sharing it with community

Comment: @Ejay do i smell sarcasm

Comment: `p.photos[0].alt_sizes[0];` and `p.photos[1].alt_sizes[0];`.

Comment: @11684 i said iterate, not select

Comment: @Dann that was a true advice :)

Comment: The answers so far have all assumed there is only one object with a `url` property in the `alt_sizes` array. Is this the case?

Comment: @PaulGrime yes. also, if anyone was wondering, I'm using the tumblr API

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function forloop(){
    var arr = p.photos, url , array_of_urls = [];
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
       url = arr[i].alt_sizes[0]['url'];
      array_of_urls .push(url);
    }
    console.log(array_of_urls, url)
    return url;
  }

var bigString = "something"+forloop()+"something";
```

Comment: and how would i go about `return`ing the result? would the normal approach work?

Comment: Depends on your application. Return the result to what?

Comment: there are multiple url which url you want?

Comment: I have a function that uses a big string that looks something like this: `"something"+forloop+"something"` where forloop is the function described

Comment: @Dann Sorry, but what should forloop function return.

Comment: @Sushil this will do, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Also possible using ECMAScript 5 `forEach` without the need for an extra library.

```
var urls = []
p.photos.forEach(function(e) {
    urls.push(e.alt_sizes[0]['url']);
});
console.log(urls);
```

Comment: May not need an extra library, but may possibly need a polyfill. Not that that's a bad thing, I'm just saying

Comment: Not at all, except IE8 (and older) the support is pretty perfect: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.forEach.

Comment: IE8 and older is still a significant audience...that's my point - I said **may need**

Answer (score -1):

Use $.each. An [example](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/H9e7P/2/)

```
 $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
 alert( key + ": " + value );

  if(typeof(value)=="object")
  {
    $.each( value, function( key, value ) {
         alert( key + ": " + value );
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: why would I need to use jQuery for such a simple end

Comment: Because it provides a better way to parse the JSON without worrying about the browser compatibility issues

Comment: I second Dann's opinion. That's basic JavaScript.

Comment: Its choice how you want of go for a solution  write something by your own or use something with is existing and tested

Comment: @NullPointerException There's no browser compatibility issues you need to worry about with looping over an object/array. Who said this is JSON anyways? There's no parsing in the question

Comment: @Ian it is JSON, however that is unimportant as the parsing is done before the snippet in question, and `p` is set as the needed part of said JSON

Answer (score -1):

```
// loop through all properties of `p` (assuming that there might be other objects besides
// `photos` that might have the `url` property we are looking for)
for(i in p){
  // ensure the property is not on the prototype
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    // loop through the array
    for(j = p[i].length; j--;){
      // check that the `url` property is there
      if(typeof p[i][j].alt_sizes[0].url != "undefined"){
        // do something with the url propert - in this case, log to console
        console.log(p[i][j].alt_sizes[0].url)
      }
    }
  }
}
```